# Spectral theorem for matrices......

Tags: real-analysis, matrices, spectral-theory

From the spectral theorem we know that

if $A$ is a symmetric matrix then there exists an orthogonal matrix $M$ such that

$A=M^{-1}DM=M^TAM$

My question is: if I have the matrix $A$ how do I find the matrixes $D$ and $M$?

Thanks a lot

Comment: As usual as we diagonalize any matrix but we normalize the eigenvectors i.e. we make them with norm $1$.

Comment: @user296113 And furthermore, when an eigenspace has dimension $>1$, we choose a orthonormal basis, say by Gram-Schmidt.

Answer (score 2):

If $A$ is symmetric, then $A$ has an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors. The eigenvectors associated with different eigenvalues are automatically orthogonal. But you have to perform Gram-Schmidt on the eigenvectors with the same eigenvalue in order to get an orthonormal basis of the eigenspace. Once you have the orthonormal basis of eigenvectors, you put them into the columns of a matrix $U=[c_1,c_2,c_3,\cdots,c_n]$. Then
\begin{align}
     AU & = [Ac_1,Ac_2,\cdots,Ac_n] \\
        & =[\lambda_1c_1,\lambda_2c_2,\cdots,\lambda_n c_n] \\
        & = [c_1,c_2,\cdots,c_n]\left[\begin{array}{cccc}\lambda_1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
                  0 & \lambda_2 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
                 \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
                  0 & 0 & 0 &\cdots &\lambda_n\end{array}\right] \\
        & = UD
\end{align}
Because $U$ is an orthogonal matrix, then $U^{T}U=UU^{T}=I$ (replace $U^T$ by conjugate transpose if you are working over complex numbers.) Then you get what you want:
$$
               A = UDU^T.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$D$ ia the diagonal matrix that has as diagonal elements the eigenvalues of $A$ and $M$ is a matrix that has as columns the corresponding eigenvectors.

Do you know how to find these? ( see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors))

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answers... Emilio, I know how to find the eigenvalues and the eigenvectors... My questions are: 1. If $A$ is symmetric, (let's say that it is $3\times 3$) I always have $3$ eigenvectors? 2. Who tells me that they are orthonormal? 3. If I have to orthonormalise them the diagonal matrix $D$ will be different from the diagonal matrix with the eigenvalues on the diagonal?

Comment: For a symmetric matrix the eigenvector of distinct eigenvalue are orthogonal. See here: http://web.mit.edu/jorloff/www/18.03-esg/notes/symmetricMatrices.pdf